# cannot resolve symbol 'Address' android studio

Tags: android, google-maps, latitude-longitude, android-location, android-gps

I am using this link [How to find postcode by latitude and logitude for UK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10279230/how-to-find-postcode-by-latitude-and-logitude-for-uk) and this link [Get current location using GPS in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22741632/get-current-location-using-gps-in-android) to get user lat and long and then convert it into post code. However, I am getting an error on Address, it says `cannot resolve symbol 'Address' android studio` and because of this `address= geoCoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1)`; and this `String postCode = address.get(0).getPostalCode();` line.

```
    Geocoder geoCoder = new Geocoder(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), Locale.getDefault());
            List<Address> address = null;

            if (geoCoder != null){
                try {
                    address= geoCoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
                if (address.size()> 0){
                    String postCode = address.get(0).getPostalCode();
                }
```

If you can help, it would be really nice. I am new to android and have no clue on how to go about solving this. If my question is not clear please let me know.

EDITED:

premission in manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

Gradel compile

```
 compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.3.23'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1'
```

Comment: Did you add Google Play Services to your gradle file?

Comment: Yep,  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.3.23'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try updating play services to the latest version 8.4.0

```
 dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
 }
```

https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup

Comment: Hi, I have managed to solve the issue, I had to import android.location.Address; I tried updating the play services but it doesn't work.

Comment: oh, I thought you had imported that already.  btw, you should be on 8.4 regardless. 4.3 is very very old...

Answer (score 3):

Solved my problem, it turned out that I had to import

```
import android.location.Address;
```