# How to get post code from lat and long android

Tags: android, latitude-longitude, android-location

I am using these two threads:

[How to find postcode by latitude and logitude for UK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10279230/how-to-find-postcode-by-latitude-and-logitude-for-uk)

[Get current location using GPS in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22741632/get-current-location-using-gps-in-android)

and have successfully managed to implement a GPStracker, however, when I try to recieve the postcode using the first thread it does not give me any post:

I have this as global variable:

```
public String receivePostCode = "";
```

and then in onCreate I have this:

```
Geocoder geoCoder = new Geocoder(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), Locale.getDefault());
        List<Address> address = null;

        if (geoCoder != null) {
            try {
                address = geoCoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (address.size() > 0) {
                receivePostCode = address.get(0).getPostalCode();

            }

        }
```

These are the global variables that I am using to recieve lat and long from my GPStracker class:

```
GPSTracker gps = new GPSTracker(getActivity());
double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
double longitude = gps.getLongitude();
```

Any help would be nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to initialise the variables inside onCreate or onCreateView, they shouldn't be initialised globally, try this, in onCreate:

```
  gps = new GPSTracker(getActivity());
  latitude = gps.getLatitude();
  longitude = gps.getLongitude();
```

and put this as global:

```
GPSTracker gps;
double latitude;
double longitude;
```